# SQLite table order by

Tags: java, sqlite

I have a table with primary key as a date.  The date is a string formatted as yyyy-MM-dd.  In my java program I display the data as MM/dd/yy.  I want the dates to display in descending order.  To accomplish this I use the following query:

```
select strftime('%m/%d/', Date) || substr(strftime('%Y', Date),3, 2) as Date from date_TBL Order by Date DESC
```

However, my dates do not display in the correct order.

2016-04-09
2016-04-08
2015-04-09

displays as

04/09/16
04/09/15
04/08/16

I assumed, incorrectly I guess, that the "order by date desc" would order by the original date (yyyy-MM-dd) and not the reformatted date (MM/dd/yy).  Is there anyway I can get around this with my query?

Comment: You could add the original date as another field selected in the query, then order by that field.  similar to "select datefield, formatteddatefield from table X order by datefield desc".  Alternatively, you could format the date AFTER retrieving the list from the table.

Comment: Don't use `as Date`. Use a different name

Comment: Good call, worked great.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Date` can refer either to the table column `Date`, or to the alias `Date` that you defined with AS in the SELECT clause.
The SQL standard specifies that in such a conflict, the table column must be chosen, but SQLite chooses the alias for compatibility with some other DBs.

To avoid this conflict, give the alias another name, or explicitly refer to the table with `date_TBL.Date`.